Do these tires present signs of uneven wear or cupping?
My SO went to the car dealership to have the winter tires installed and told the car badly needed alignment. They've been telling me that since my first tire change (which was 8 months after I bought it) and I'm suspecting they are being dishonest. The car is 3 years old and I seldom use it. It has about 10000 miles. Hadn't had alignment done before since I never noticed any signs it was needed. Steering wheel is centered, car doesn't pull on one side and, to my eye anyway, the tires don't seem to show any signs of suspicious wear. I'd like to get your opinion though on that point since I'm no expert, do these tires shows signs of uneven wear or cupping?


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Typically, we don't answer tire health questions, however, I think I can answer this in a way to help you understand what you need to do to diagnose the tires for yourself. Your images to me don't show cupping, but it's a little more tricky than seeing it (in most cases).
To understand if your tires are cupping, you need to run your hand around the circumference of the tire on the outside edge of the tread. With your hand placed lightly on the tread, draw it around the circumference in one direction, then do the same in the other direction. If the tire grabs at your hand in one direction, but is fairly smooth going the other, this is indication of cupping. You can more quickly discern it by feeling it than you can by looking for it.
As an aside, it is a really good idea to get your car aligned when you put new tires on your vehicle. The reasoning behind this is that tires are (for most people) an investment, and not cheap. You want the most from your investment. A bad alignment can tear up a set of new tires in short order. No sense in destroying $1000 worth of tires because you didn't want to spend $150 to get an alignment done.

Thank you for the explanation, that helps! Quick question, when you say new tires do you mean brand new tires or when I have them changed between seasons? For brand new tires, that was my understanding it was recommended to have it aligned but I thought it was ok when just changing tires between seasons to skip it if there are no unusual signs. The winter tires they installed yesterday I had them since 2022 when I got the car.

@JostKristin - Exactly. New means new. As long as you're not seeing any alignment issues when you do the tire changes (summer to winter, or vise-versa), you can get away without doing one.

Thanks for the help, that was very informative. I lightly ran my hands on the tires and didn't feel them grabbing in one direction.

I put new tyres on mine recently, the garage, having observed uneven wear on the old ones, did an alignment check, brought me the printout to see, then did the adjustment and rechecked- so I have before and after alignment printouts to show what was changed
